# How to use UIProgressView while loading of a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiprogressview

i am developing an application where i am loading a urlrequest in the UIWebView and it happened successfully.

But now i am trying to display a UIProgressView when the loading is in progress( starting from 0.0 to 1.0), which is changed dynamically with the progress of loading.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UIWebView doesn't give you any progress information in the normal mode. What you need to do is first fetch your data asynchronously using an NSURLConnection.
When the NSURLConnection delegate method `connection:didReceiveResponse`, you're going to take the number you get from `expectedContentLength` and use that as your max value. Then, inside the delegate method `connection:didReceiveData`, you're going to use the `length` property of the NSData instance to tell you how far along you are, so your progress fraction will be `length / maxLength` , normalized to between 0.0 and 1.0.

Finally, you're going to init the webview with data instead of a URL (in your `connection:didFinishLoading` delegate method).

Two caveats:

1. It is possible that the `expectedContentLength` property of the NSURLResponse is going to be **-1** (`NSURLReponseUnknownLength` constant). In that case, I would suggest throwing up a standard UIActivityIndicator that you shut off inside `connection:didFinishLoading`.
2. Make sure that any time you manipulate a visible control from one of the NSURLConnection delegate methods, you do so by calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:` - otherwise you'll start getting the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

Using this technique, you can show a progress bar when you know how much data you're supposed to get, and a spinner when you don't know.

Comment: The problem with implementing the NSURLConnection data fetch on top of the UIWebView load request is that you're grabbing the same data twice, which is wasteful on a lightweight connection. You can load the NSData instance directly into the UIWebView with `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`, but this can compromise other facets of using UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this subclass of UIWebView which uses the private UIWebView methods - therefore, this solution is not 100% AppStore safe (though some apps do almost 100% use it: Facebook, Google app, ...).

https://github.com/petr-inmite/imtwebview

Answer (score -2):

Using NSURLConnection you are fetching the same data twice,waste of time because it can slow down the user interaction it loads the data twice ,consumes  internet data.It is better to make a **uiprogress based on timer and when the webview successfuly loaded the webpage it will show the uiprogress loading**.in that case you can show a dynamic uiprogress everytime the webpage is loaded.. dont forget to create a uiprogress view and named it myProgressview and set it in file owner's.

HERE IS THE CODE HOPE IT HELPS

```
@synthesize myProgressView;
- (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)sender
{      //if the progress view is = 100% the progress stop
    if(myProgressView.progress==1.0)
    {
        [timer invalidate]; 
    }
   else
         //if the progress view is< 100% the progress increases
       myProgressView.progress+=0.5;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ //this is the code used in order to load the site
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.playbuzz.org/";
    myWebview.delegate = self;
   [myWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:urlAddress]]];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{    ///timer for the progress view

 timer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                          target:self
                          selector:@selector(updateProgress:)
                          userInfo:myProgressView
                          repeats:YES]retain];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myProgressView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

> this code  and idea really helps me in solving my problem.