# How to use UIProcessView With UIWebView

Tags: ios

I've a `UIWebView` connected to a site that loads just fine. Now what, i want to do is connect a `UIProgressView` so that the `UIProgressView` shows the status of the loading of the page. I have already added a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. But i just don't really like it and doesn't fit the look and feel of my app. So, I want to use the `UIProgressView` instead.

Please take into consideration that i'm new to developing for iOS. So, my question is how can i assign a `UIProcessView` to a `UIWebView`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560721/uiwebview-loading-progress-and-adjust-web-page-to-fit-the-view-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party controls

https://github.com/petr-inmite/imtwebview

Comment: Your code is incorrect, since you will simulate progress only after the webview completes the data download (You are starting the timer in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method). Ideally you should download data using `NSURLConnection` and load this data in webview. Use the progress info to display the progress view.