# How to show progressBar when video is uploading?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a progressBar when video is getting uploaded 
any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You will get more support from SO if you show what you have tried so far and make effort in researching the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example did you search other answers - [take a look at this for ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560721/uiwebview-loading-progress-and-adjust-web-page-to-fit-the-view-page?lq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSURLConnection** for upload video. Then use the delegate method **didSendBodyData** and do something like this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
{
  yourProgresView.progress = totalBytesWritten/totalBytesWritten;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

drag the progressive view that u have placed in the view controller and then by making -(void)progressive view write the coding that on how much time u want it to show the progress and all the details in the view.