# How to create Downloading Bar to UIWebview

Tags: iphone

I need to create downloading bar, when URL is loading on UIWebview to my application.

I need to following format when URL is loading time to my application.

[image]

Comment: THIS WILL HELP
UIPROGRESS IN WEBVIEW


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19173341/2314592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the native `UIProgressView` for this.

To do that, use `UIWebViewDelegate` and implement `webViewDidStartLoad:` and `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

I don't think it's possible to easily show an indicator about how much of resources have been loaded so far due to the fact that `UIWebView` is rather limited on iOS, you'd have to create some kind of smooth, timed animation.

If I was you, I'd go for `UIActivityIndicatorView` to display that "spinning circle" indicator while the page is loading.

Comment: hi BastiBense, i created like that using UIProgressView by your advice.   I used webViewDidFinishLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad and then i did some calculation. like as this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255261/add-nsurlconnection-loading-process-on-uiprogressview  Thanks BastiBense..