# Add NSURLConnection loading process on UIProgressView

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uiprogressview

I created a `UIProgressView`. But i used `NSTimer` to `UIProgressView's` process .  Now I need to integrate `UIProgressView` process, when URL is loading. `UIProgressView's` size will be depends upon the `NSURLConnection's` data.

I used the following code to `NSURLConnection`.

```
-(void)load {
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feeds.epicurious.com/newrecipes"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:60];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [connection release];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Warning"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Network Connection Failed?"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSLog(@"Error");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    responsetext = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your didReceiveResponse function you could get the total filesize like so:
`_totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;`.

In your didReceiveData function you can then add up to a total bytes received counter:
`_receivedDataBytes += [data length];`

Now in order to set the progressbar to the correct size you can simply do:
`MyProgressBar.progress = _receivedDataBytes  / (float)_totalFileSize`

(either in the didReceiveData function or somewhere else in your code)

Don't forget to add the variables that hold the number of bytes to your class!

I hope this helps..

EDIT: Here's how you could implement the delegates in order to update progressview

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   _receivedDataBytes += [data length];
   MyProgressBar.progress = _receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize;
   [responseData appendData:data];
 }
```

Comment: How to declare response in didReceiveResponse , please edit the following code.   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

 totalFileSize=response.expectedContentLength;
 receivedDataBytes += [data length];
 NSLog(@"totalFileSize / totalFileSize = %f",receivedDataBytes / totalFileSize);

 [responseData appendData:data];
}

Comment: didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData are 2 different delegates. It should be: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
totalFileSize=response.expectedContentLength;
}

and remove that line from didReceiveData

Comment: Edited my answer. I forgot to mention that one of the values you divide with should be casted to a float. Since you could otherwise end up with an integer, without float precision.

Comment: B_vdl : Thanks for your answer. my problem is solved. but i edit some code. please check and tell your command...

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

 
 totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;
 
 responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

 receivedDataBytes += [data length];
 NSLog(@"receivedDataBytes / (float)totalFileSize; = %2f",(1+((float)totalFileSize / (float)receivedDataBytes)*1000));

 // MyProgressBar.progress = receivedDataBytes / (float)totalFileSize;
 
 [responseData appendData:data];
}

Comment: I get output as following

totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.594320
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.836173
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.915154
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.948283
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.959876
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.973168
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.978955
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.982887
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.984343
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.985732
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.987008
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.988136

Comment: totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.988829
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.989402
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.990069
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.990952
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.991410
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.991799
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.992157
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.992551
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.993423
totalFileSize / receivedDataBytes; = 0.993597

Comment: See the reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  the progress property expects a value between 0.0 and 1.0 where 1.0 indicates completion of the task. Thus setting this property with the values recieved from the division should do the trick!

Comment: i also got the values between 0.0 to 1.0.  But i used the above calculation..  My problem is solved. But i dont know my code is correct or wrong. But it works well. if any mistake in my calculation please tell me.

Comment: The code is allright. But there are certain (offtopic) ways to optimalize. You access the progressview every time you receive data. You could add a timer somewhere else in the code to minimalize the times the progressview object is accessed.

Furthermore (totally offtopic), you currently add received data to an object in memory. This is fine with small files. However if you download bigger files (over 20 MB) you might experience some severe memory problems. Workaround is to save directly to disk.

I will now stop answering to this thread before we get even more offtopic :).