# How to indicate a webpage loading progress in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, progress-bar, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use UIProgressView while loading of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900151/how-to-use-uiprogressview-while-loading-of-a-uiwebview)

In my app i have a UIViewController with a UIWebView and a toolbar as a subviews. 
The toolbar has a UITextField for the address. When loading a page the address field should indicate the loading progress of the webpage something like Safari's address bar or Facebook app for iOS when loading an external link.

The problem that i face is that i can't find a way to show the progress of the page when loading, making the address field(UIText field) fill with a color.

Is there any way to do that or a component already made for this?

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge there is no way that you could read the progress of a HTML page being loaded into an UIWebView. However I have an idea what you could do. It is a bit "around the corner" but if displaying a progress bar while loading a HTML page into a UIWebView is REALLY important to you, here is what you could do:

1. Do not load the HTML directly into the UIWebView. Load it into memory first (you can use the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library to do that really easily).
2. ASIHTTPRequest offers a delegate method that allows you to access the progress of the request. Use that to display the progress.
3. Once the HTML finished loading, render it into the UIWebView using `[UIWebView loadHTMLString:]`

As I mentioned before this is really unconventional, but if you really need the progress to be displayed it is the only way I can think of.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. i'll give it a try.