# UIWbView multiple URL loading with UIProgressView in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, url, uiwebview, uiprogressbar

I am trying to create an iPhone app as in the fig below:

[image]

In this i am dynamically adding some imageviews dynamically into a uiscroll view. Each imageview contains a UIButton and UIProgressView. When click on each it should different urls and the loading of each url should appear on the corresponding UIProgressView. I am using asynchronous method and it should load multiple progress views at the same time. 
Here is the code i have used,

```
- (void)startDownload:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int btnTag = btn.tag;
    selectedTag = btn.tag;

    for (int x=0; x < [urlArray count]; x++) {
        if (btnTag == x) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlArray objectAtIndex:x]];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Expected length: %lld ",response.expectedContentLength);
                                   }];
            if (theConnection) {
                receivedData = [NSMutableData data];                    
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Connection failed");
            }            
        }
    }
}

- (void)makeMyProgressMove{

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[mainView viewWithTag:selectedTag];
    UIProgressView *currentProgress = (UIProgressView *)[image viewWithTag:selectedTag];
    NSLog(@"Prog tag: %d",currentProgress.tag);

    if(currentProgress)
    {
        float actualProgress =  (_receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize);
        currentProgress.progress =  actualProgress;

    } else {
        NSLog( @"couldn't get the progress view for the image with tag: %d", selectedTag );
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response { 
    _totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    _receivedDataBytes += [data length];

    NSLog(@"Receiving data: %2f", _receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize);

    if ((_receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize) < 1) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(makeMyProgressMove) withObject: NULL waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    else if ((_receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize) == 1){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(makeMyProgressMove) withObject: NULL waitUntilDone:NO];
        _receivedDataBytes = 0;
        _totalFileSize = 0;
    }
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
}
```

But its not working.
Any idea?

Comment: this can help

[uiprogress in webview answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19173341/2314592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allocate each UIWebView with different url and and addSubView UIActivityIndicatorView to every UIWebView.Give tag for each UIActivityIndicator ..

```
-(void)action  {

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];//give y value incremented frame.

UIActivityIndicatorView  *av = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
av.frame=CGRectMake(145, 160, 25, 25);
av.center = webView.center;
av.tag  = INDICATOR_TAG;
[webView addSubview:av];
webView.delegate = self;
[av startAnimating];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

 UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [webView viewWithTag:INDICATOR_TAG];
indicator.hidden = YES;

}
```

call this action{} method for showing multiple times.

## **EDIT**

UIWebView doesn't give you any progress information in the normal mode. What you need to do is first fetch your data asynchronously using an NSURLConnection. When the NSURLConnection delegate method c*onnection:didReceiveResponse*, you're going to take the number you get from expectedContentLength and use that as your max value. Then, inside the delegate method connection:didReceiveData, you're going to use the length property of the NSData instance to tell you how far along you are, so your progress fraction will be length / maxLength , normalized to between 0 and 1.

Finally, you're going to init the webview with data instead of a URL (in your connection:didFinishLoading delegate method).

Reference :
[How to use UIProgressView while loading of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900151/how-to-use-uiprogressview-while-loading-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: but, actually I want to handle multiple urls at the same time. So how can I manage the delegate methods? Because each webview will have different progress bar controllers.

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  this is the delegate method and it will give you which webView loaded