# How can I use progressView during URL is loading?

Tags: ios, xcode, url, uiwebview, uiprogressview

I want the progressView working while my URL is loading. What should I do for that?

here's my .m code:

```
-(void)openURL{
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
[[self view] addSubview:webView];
}

- (IBAction)goto:(id)sender {


[self openURL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:), specifically:

```
-(void)openURL{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webView.delegate = self;
    // ... rest of method as above ...
}

- webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Start progress.
}

- webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Stop progress.
}
```

Comment: Whilst technically true this doesn't explain how a progress bar can be used. Those delegate callbacks would only signal a 0 to 100 call

Comment: There is no way to get incremental progress info from UIWebView, you can only show an indefinite spinner.  If the question is to show incremental progress, then it's a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900151/how-to-use-uiprogressview-while-loading-of-a-uiwebview) and many others.

Comment: The OP probably needs to be a bit clearer then, one upvote to you sir.

Comment: Eh, your criticism was fair.  They probably did want progressive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
[progressView startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [webView loadRequest:yourRequest];

    [progressView stopAnimating];
    [progressView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

This will start the progress view before the operation begins, and will stop and remove it when it finishes.